# Vertically anchor an image to its top in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have some code to have an image of random size spread to the full width of a container + vertically center inside the container. But what I need is to anchor it at the top.

In CSS i would use background-position, but it's not supported in React Native. I feel I've tried every combination of resizeMode, absolute positioning, etc - but still haven't been able to figure it out.

```
<View style={{
  flex: 1,
  height: 120,
}}>
  <Image source={{uri: source}} style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  }}>
  </Image>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `justifyContent: 'top'`?

Comment: @MendyK there's no value 'top' for this property. the closest thing is 'flex-start' and i didn't do the trick alone

Comment: @GuillaumeGuillaume did you find a solution ?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to (top-)align the image. Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution in 2020.. any news?

Comment: its 2021.....any news on this??

Comment: its 2024... anyone found a way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems crazy that there is still not a standard way of anchoring an image in React Native as there is in regular css (at least if there is, I stall haven't found it). But this lib does the trick for me:

[react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the height of the image *h*, then you can show the full image first then hide the bottom part with a view container of static height eg. *250*:

```
<View style={{ height: 250 }}>
  <Image source={{ uri: source }} style={{ width: null, height: h }} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a trick to do that

You need to wrap the wanted height in a View with a overflow hidden
And set a large height in the image style

```
const WANTED_HEIGHT = 170
<View style={{ height: WANTED_HEIGHT, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri }}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: 500,
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
  return (
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              height: 120,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Hello ")}>
              <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>Anchor Tag</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: "https://shoutem.github.io/img/ui-toolkit/examples/image-3.png"
              }}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: 100,
                resizeMode: "cover"
              }}
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: thanks! but this is actually not the outcome i'm looking for. the visible part of your image is it's vertical center, but i want the vertical top, aka the part with the sky